# Multi variant testing reporting issue

Tags: content-testing

I have created a `multivariant test` for two different components and I have activated test.

***Issue:***

When I go to `experience editor` and click on `Test Result`, all fields are blank.

[image]

***Error***

Below error I can see in console:

```
Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={9C50A6D1-4B95-476E-8D45-8E890E16F542}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b9C50A6D1-4B95-476E-8D45-8E890E16F542%7d%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_site%3Dacu%26sc_vercomp%3D1&lang=en&pageSite=acu&version=1:447 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.highlightChromes (Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={9C50A6D1-4B95-476E-8D45-8E890E16F542}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b9C50A6D1-4B95-476E-8D45-8E890E16F542%7d%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_site%3Dacu%26sc_vercomp%3D1&lang=en&pageSite=acu&version=1:447)
    at Object.activate (Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={9C50A6D1-4B95-476E-8D45-8E890E16F542}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b9C50A6D1-4B95-476E-8D45-8E890E16F542%7d%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_site%3Dacu%26sc_vercomp%3D1&lang=en&pageSite=acu&version=1:417)
    at Object.changeShowOptimization (14195247787791118138.JS:1448)
    at Object.changeShowOptimization (ExperienceEditorProxy.js:36)
    at ExperienceEditor.PipelinesUtil.generateRequestProcessor.value (Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId={570A52B6-6755-461A-8052-5B95EF766F74}&itemId={9C50A6D1-4B95-476E-8D45-8E890E16F542}&deviceId={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}&database=master&mode=edit&url=%2F%3Fsc_mode%3Dedit%26sc_itemid%3D%7b9C50A6D1-4B95-476E-8D45-8E890E16F542%7d%26sc_version%3D1%26sc_lang%3Den%26sc_site%3Dacu%26sc_vercomp%3D1&lang=en&pageSite=acu&version=1:464)
    at Object.onRequestProcessorSuccessCallback (ExperienceEditor.js:1020)
    at Object.success (ExperienceEditor.js:995)
    at fire (jquery-2.1.1.js:3073)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.js:3185)
    at done (jquery-2.1.1.js:8251)
```